# Cronjob(s) for multiple users

Tags: cron

I have following case which may be is simple but I don't know which way is logically correct and how to do it exactly.

I have multiple sites in `/www/` each site is in own directory and user

```
/www/site1/  // user site1
/www/site2/  // user site2
/www/site3/  // user site3
```

Now I want to make cronjob which will run PHP script and will update one table in database of each site.

The script and actual job aren't problem. The problem is how to do it properly? How to create for each user job? Cronjob will run every half an hour if it's matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new user - let's call them `allsites`.

Add the `allsites` user to the `/etc/group` for `site1`, `site2` and `site3` users.

Run the script as the `allsites` user.

Then run a single script with the *different details per site* included in the script. For (a very basic) example. A copy of `script-name.sh` is located in each of the `$LIST` directories:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The base location of each site
LIST="/path/to/site1 /path/to/site2 /path/to/site3"

# Place script-name.sh in each of the above paths
SCRIPT_NAME="script-name.sh"

for i in $LIST
do
    sh "${i}/${SCRIPT_NAME}"
done
```

Another basic example would be something like the following. A single script will pull in a custom config.

```
#!/bin/sh

# The base location of each site
LIST="/path/to/site1 /path/to/site2 /path/to/site3"

# Place details for each site in config.sh in each of the above paths
CONFIG="config.sh"

for i in $LIST
do
    # Pull in the config for the current site
    . "${i}/${CONFIG}"
    # Add your commands here that use the details from $CONFIG
    echo "EXAMPLE: user name: $username"
done
```

The `config.sh` which contains the unique details per site would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# User name for DB connection??
username="site1user"
```

Comment: But I should create 3 different files ( with identical scripts inside ) just credentials for database would be different.

Comment: but like this again is only one script? `SCRIPT_NAME="script-name.sh"`

Comment: Added another example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just last question. In `config.sh` I should write `dbuser`, `dbname`, `dbpass` and `table`, right?

Comment: Yes, you can add those details to each of the `config.sh` scripts. If you are using MySQL 5.6+ you should really be using `mysql_config_editor` to set details and not pass the password on the command line or store it in a file. You then use the `--login-path=...` option - but that is really another question.

Comment: Thanks. But still can't understand how to structure `config.sh` so when it starts reading it to know for which site are credentials which is reading at the moment..

Comment: Run (and edit) the example test script above. It should make things clear.

Comment: Oh, I see now. So each site has his `config.sh` in which I have username, password, dbname .. etc. And in script which loop them instead of `echo "EXAMPLE: user name: $username"` I will put path to the `php` script for example which will be executed, right?

Comment: Sounds correct to me :]

Comment: Thanks very much. Accepting answer since it's helping me to start and understand how should be.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that:

> each site is in own directory and user

```
/www/site1/  // **user** site1
/www/site2/  // **user** site2
/www/site3/  // **user** site3
```

On your output username are the same, it's correct?

If users are actually different in your place I create three separate crons for each of them:

```
for i in user1 user2 user3; do crontab -u $i -e ; done
```

and threw rule prepared for each of them, for example (where **site_dir** are your **site{1,2,3}**:

```
0,30 * * * * sh -c "cd /www/site_dir/ && /usr/bin/php ./tool.php -c Table_Update"
```

Comment: Their databases credentials etc. are different. So that's why they must be different jobs for each one which will load same file replicated 3 times because of diff credentials to db..?